# Using pointers to objects in priority queue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, priority-queue

I am trying to use a priority_queue for an object.

To compare the two objects I wrote the following construct:

```
struct lessThanCost
{
    bool operator()(pNode*&lhs, pNode* &rhs)
    {
        return lhs->getCost() < rhs->getCost();
    }
};
```

I am using pNode* instead of pNode. I have initialized the priority queue as:

```
priority_queue < pNode*, vector<pNode*>, lessThanCost>  frontier;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __thiscall problemNode::getCost(void)" (?getCost@problemNode@@QAENXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall lessThanCost::operator()(class problemNode * &,class problemNode * &)" (??RlessThanCost@@QAE_NAAPAVproblemNode@@0@Z)
```

What is the reason of this error and how can I fix that?

Comment: You don't have a getCost method defined in class problemNode.

Comment: @stark I had two pNode.cpp files due to some reason. In one file the getCost() method implementation was written but it wasn't in the other file. VS 2013 was telling me that there is such a method available for lhs and rhs. After reading your comment, I simply copy pasted the getCost() method from the first pNode.cpp file to the second pNode.cpp and it started to work. Can you explain why was this happening?